# Groupby in Groupby and random Sampling

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame(data={'ID':[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3], 'prod':['A', 'B', 'C','D', 'E', 'F'], 'category':['cat1', 'cat1', 'cat1', 'cat1', 'cat2', 'cat2']})
```

[image]

How to randomly sample 1 `ID` per `category` to get for example:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

One solution is to loop over each group of category:

```
import random
groups_df = []
grouped = data.groupby(['category'])

list_of_groups = list(grouped.groups.keys())

for k in list_of_groups:
    group = grouped.get_group(k)
    l = group.ID.unique().tolist()
    group.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    random.shuffle(l)
    l = l[:1]
    df = group[group['ID'].isin(l) ]
    
    groups_df.append(df)
# concat all df
df = pd.concat(groups_df, axis=0)
```